# tablayout is not displaying Data properly on navigation of BottomNavigation items

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, bottomnavigationview

i am working on this college project where i have to make a job portal app
i have used a bottom Navigation view and within one of the menu item i have placed a tab layout once i start my app it works fine and the tabs works fine. But once i move from one menu to other and come back to the menu item with tabs in it the tabs are not working properly.
i have used a recycler view in tabs and the list is displayed at first but once i move to the third bottom menu the list is no longer displayed 
below is the code of my tabs layout and bottom navigation view

```
  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
  mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = 
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:

                transaction.replace(R.id.content,new 
    HomeFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_JobBoard:

                transaction.replace(R.id.content,new 
   JobBoardFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:

                transaction.replace(R.id.content,new 
    NotificationBoardFragment()).commit();

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
 findViewById(R.id.navigation);





 navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
 (mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content,new HomeFragment()).commit();
     }

}
```

JOBBoardFragment class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs, container, false);

    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs);
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("saved"));
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Inbox"));
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("sent"));
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    //       SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new 
  SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    //       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    return view;


}
```

layout file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

 tools:context="com.example.jimmy.workmen.
   DashboardFragment.JobBoardFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"
        app:expanded="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"

           android:theme="@style/Base.DialogWindowTitleBackground.AppCompat"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

class tabspageradapter

```
 public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context mContext ;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"saved", "inbox", "sent"};

public TabsPagerAdapter( FragmentManager fm) {

    super(fm);
    //  mContext = context;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

    if (position == 0) {
        return new InboxFragment();
    } else if (position == 1){
        return new SavedFragment();
    } else if (position == 2){
        return new SentFragment();
    } else {
        return null;
    }


}

@Override

public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}






}
```

Comment: Can you share `TabsPagerAdapter`?

Comment: i have added the TabsPagerAdapter class

Comment: You don't need those three `addTab()` calls in `onCreateView()` by the way, they are already being created by your `TabsPagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this problem.

First solution is that `TabsPagerAdapter` extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Although I am not sure why this works, it probably related to memory-efficient approach of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, i.e. it may be creating fragments from scratch when you come back again.

Second solution is to pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to your `TabsPagerAdapter` because of your implicitly nested fragment structure due to ViewPager:

```
TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

I think second solution is way to go and more information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

Comment: Yes second solutions works fine but i still didnt get that why was it happening because it was just the recycler view that was not displayed rest of the tabs were fine

Comment: Is that fragment include only the recyclerview you mention? Or are there other views in that fragment and they are visible but only recyclerview is empty/absent?

Comment: Only the recycler view was empty rest of the views were working fine

Comment: In which function of fragment do you bind data to your recycler view?